# How can i set different Tooltip for all Items in Checkboxlist in Win forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I want to add description field as Tooltip. Here is what i am currently doing:

```
SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Name,Description FROM Test", Database.Connection);
SqlDataAdapter adptr6 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd6);
DataSet ds6 = new DataSet();
adptr6.Fill(ds6, "Test");

TestCheckedListBox.DataSource = ds6.Tables["Test"];
TestCheckedListBox.ValueMember = "Id";
TestCheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: No there is no direct way to have a tooltip for each Item. The duplicate explains a possible implementation

Comment: @Steve "The duplicate explains a possible implementation" Means?

Comment: It means that you need to write your own code to handle the tooltip following the hints given in the accepted answer and in some other answers that elaborate on the initial idea.